# How can I use send_keys at random intervals with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

For example, when writing "Hello", I would like to wait for a random amount of time between 0.03 and 0.2 seconds for each character to be typed.

Is it possible to accomplish this using a send_keys function with a random wait time between 0.03 and 0.2 seconds for each character?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/X/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get ('https://example.com/login')

driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]").send_keys('H')
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.03,0.2))

driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]").send_keys('e')
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.03,0.2))

driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]").send_keys('l')
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.03,0.2))

driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]").send_keys('l')
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.03,0.2))

driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]").send_keys('o')
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.03,0.2))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "single send_keys function" ? Why isnt looping over the elements of the string "Hello" an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it. Making a function that breaks your string into characters, and sends them one at a time will accomplish this without hard-coding anything:

```
def send_keys_delayed(elementName, str)
   for char in str:
      driver.find_element_by_name(elementName).send_keys(char)
      time.sleep(random.uniform(0.03,0.2))
```